# Express.js backend not saving cookie to Nuxt.js frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, nuxt.js

I've built an authorization server with Express.js that works when testing with Postman where it saves the access and rotating refresh token as signed cookies.
However, what I completely forgot, was that my backend and frontend are two completely separate servers and domains. I tried enabling the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, but that didn't work. I don't get any error messages, the cookies simply aren't being saved.

Here is my login controller from the backend:

```js
const userLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) return res.sendStatus(400);

  try {
    const login = await loginUser(email, password);
    if (login == 'wrong_email_or_password') return res.status(200).json({ error: login });

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    res.cookie('access', login.accessToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: (env != 'dev'), signed: true });
    res.cookie('refresh', login.refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: (env != 'dev'), signed: true });

    res.status(200).json(login);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    res.sendStatus(500) && next();
  }
}
```

And after I encountered some CORS issues, I also did `app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));`, which resolved the issue. For production I'll probably also add a CORS-whitelist.

And here's my Nuxt.js method that will be called upon submitting the register-form:

```js
async register () {
  try {
    if (!(this.firstname && this.lastname && this.username && this.email && this.password)) throw new Error('Pflichtfelder ausfüllen')

    const res = await axios.post(`${this.$axios.defaults.baseURL}register`, {
      firstname: this.firstname,
      lastname: this.lastname,
      username: this.username,
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }, {
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: 'include'
    })

    console.log(res)

    this.$router.go()
  } catch (e) {
    this.error = e.message
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

I wish I could provide some more helpful information other than "doesn't work, help pls", but as I said, I don't get any errors whatsoever, so I really don't even know where to look. :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your browser probably considers the cookies sent by your backend third-party cookies and blocks them, because the HTML page from which the request is made is on a different top-level domain.

Comment: But they don't appear under "Blocked cookies"

Comment: Send the cookies (from your server) as a response of your API POST call to your front-end and save them on your front-end with Nuxt. Also, be sure that the query is properly sent (and it's response) in the network tab.

Comment: I would prefer to do it server-side tho, as I want to sign the cookies

Comment: This is the response header: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1893
ETag: W/"765-ZZttm2jpsMSPXjmaK38ZJbSNZbM"
Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2022 16:02:45 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it would seem that what I'm trying to do is impossible. Cookies coming from third-party domains are not allowed, which makes sense now that I think of it...

For anyone interested, my solution is to just save both tokens in `localStorage`. Since I am using rotating refresh tokens this isn't that big of a deal.